# Dependency not found error while importing a file

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add a dependency in a Vue.js Component's script tag.

`import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService.js'`

The error I get is -

```
This dependency was not found:

* @services/Api in ./src/services/AuthenticationService.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save @services/Api
```

My path structure is client->src->services.

My AuthenticationService.js file

```
import Api from '@services/Api'

export default {
    register(credentials) {
        return Api.post()('register', credentials)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@/services/Api` (see the `/`?) in the `AuthenticationService`. Otherwise the bundler assumes that `@services/x` is an installed package in `node_modules` (and obviously isn't able to find it).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.